# Bash process substitution with pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Suppose I have a file t.txt with many lines containing 'a'.  I m puzzled why this doesn't work:

```
cat <(tail -f t.txt | grep a)
```

The above command just hangs without printing anything, even though every line has a match.  Is this because cat is waiting for output of "tail" instead of "grep"?  How can I fix this?

Btw, I tried another variant with double process substitution:

```
cat <(grep a <(tail -f t.txt))
```

This also hangs without printing anything.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add grep's option `--line-buffered`.

See `man grep`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works.  I think I understand it now: without --line-buffered, grep will try to buffer the whole output, which will never finish, since tail -f never finishes.

Answer (score 2):

For programs that don't take a `--line-buffered` argument, you can use `stdbuf`:

```
cat <(tail -f t.txt | stdbuf -oL grep a)
```

How this works is sheer magic; it's best not to think about it.